# Flutter: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget - Listener Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

**Edit: I solved this. The code I included did not contain my issue. I had several places where I had Flexible(child: Container), and removing those fixed my issue.**

I'm trying to make a ListView with individually selectable containers. It works, but I'm getting the Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget error, and I don't know why. Every flexible and expanded widget is inside a row or column. I've also tried wrapping ListView in a container or expanded widget.

Debug console output:

> The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of
> type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept
> ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
>
> Usually, this means that the Flexible widget has the wrong ancestor
> RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Flexible widgets are placed directly
> inside Flex widgets. The offending Flexible is currently placed inside
> a Listener widget.
>
> The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the
> incompatible parent data was:   DecoratedBox ← Container ← Flexible ←
> Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ←
> Column ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← ⋯ When the exception was
> thrown, this was the stack

Relevant code:

```
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: 690,
          ),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    for (int i = counter; i < allWorkouts.length; i++)
                        buildTile(i),
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                        buildTile(i),
                    ]),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
```

```
  Widget buildTile(int i) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            // if statement prevents excessive adding to list
            if (allWorkouts[i].isInitialized == false) {
              for (int j = 0;
                  j < allWorkouts[i].exercises.length;
                  ++j) {
                for (int k = 0;
                    k < allWorkouts[i].exercises[j].sets;
                    k++) {
                  // repsCompleted initialized with initial reps value
                  allWorkouts[i]
                      .exercises[j]
                      .repsCompleted
                      .add(allWorkouts[i].exercises[j].reps +
                          1);
                }
              }
              allWorkouts[i].isInitialized = true;
            }
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => WorkoutPage(i)))
                .then((value) {
              setState(() {});
            });
          },
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: i == counter
                    ? Border.all(color: Colors.red)
                    : Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                color: widgetNavColor,
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(allWorkouts[i].name,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17,
                        )),
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                      height: 20,
                      color: Colors.transparent),
                  Column(children: [
                    for (int j = 0;
                        j <
                            allWorkouts[i]
                                .exercises
                                .length;
                        j++)
                      Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Row(children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Align(
                              alignment:
                                  Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                  allWorkouts[i]
                                      .exercises[j]
                                      .name,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                          if (allWorkouts[i]
                                      .exercises[j]
                                      .weight %
                                  1 ==
                              0)
                            Expanded(
                                child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment
                                        .centerRight,
                                    child: Text(
                                        "${allWorkouts[i].exercises[j].sets}x${allWorkouts[i].exercises[j].reps} ${allWorkouts[i].exercises[j].weight ~/ 1}lb",
                                        style:
                                            const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 17,
                                        ))))
                          else
                            Expanded(
                                child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment
                                        .centerRight,
                                    child: Text(
                                        "${allWorkouts[i].exercises[j].sets}x${allWorkouts[i].exercises[j].reps} ${allWorkouts[i].exercises[j].weight.toString()}lb",
                                        style:
                                            const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize:
                                                    17)))),
                        ]),
                        Divider(
                            // larger divider if not at end of list
                            height: j !=
                                    allWorkouts[i]
                                            .exercises
                                            .length -
                                        1
                                ? 25
                                : 10,
                            color: Colors.transparent),
                      ])
                  ]),
                ],
              ))),
      const Divider(height: 5, color: Colors.transparent),
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Listview.builder should not be child of Column. Use Expanded as parents Widget. It will remove your incorrect use of parentWidget.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed made the parent of ListView Expanded and removed the column. I now get the error "The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Padding widget." I remove the parent container of the expanded widget and I get the same error as the original post.